# Asterisk: How to enable the HTTPS mini server?

Tags: asterisk

I am attempting to enable the HTTPS mini server in Asterisk with little luck.

Here is my http.conf:

```
[general]
enabled=yes
bindaddr=192.168.254.26
bindport=8088
tlsenable=yes
tlsbindaddr=192.168.254.26:8089
tlscertfile=</etc/asterisk/keys/asterisk.pem>
```

From the Asterisk terminal I can see the http server is running, but not the https server:

```
ubuntu*CLI> http show status
HTTP Server Status:
Prefix: 
Server Enabled and Bound to 192.168.254.26:8088

Enabled URI's:
/httpstatus => Asterisk HTTP General Status
/phoneprov/... => Asterisk HTTP Phone Provisioning Tool
/static/... => Asterisk HTTP Static Delivery
/ws => Asterisk HTTP WebSocket

Enabled Redirects:
  None.
```

Strangely, not setting an address for `tlsbindaddr` gives me `HTTPS Server Enabled and Bound to (null)` and it's not listening on any ports.

I am not seeing any errors specific to the HTTP server in my logs. Here is my message log: http://pastie.org/10814745

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to your tlscertfile should not be enclosed between < >
Those symbols mean that this value is optional.